Unable to find the Epson TM Printer Using Android SDK on Emulator
I am unable to scan and locate the Epson TM printer using the ePOS_SDK_Android when running the application on the emulator. However, I can successfully find, connect, and print from a real device without any issues.
Additionally, I am unable to scan and connect via the emulator using their included sample app, although it works fine on a real device.
Is there a way to make it work on the Android emulator?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.
